# How can I compute the previous and next chars?

Tags: java, string

My goal is to return a string that is made up of characters that are 1 before and 1 after each character in the given string in the ASCII table.

For example, `dog` should return `cenpfh`.

```
public String encrypt(String s) {
   if (s.length() == 1) {
       String one = "";
       one += (s.charAt(0)-1) + (s.charAt(0)+1);
       return one;
   } else { .. }
}
```

This is the code I have so far, and I have no idea how to continue. This doesn't even work for a single character, for example, "172" is returned for "V". Could anyone point me in the right direction? Really stumped right now.

Comment: this `(s.charAt(0)-1) + (s.charAt(0)+1)` evaluates to `int`, that's why you get a number instead of two chars. Use `StringBuilder` to append chars one by one.

Comment: why do you want to use recursion?

Comment: Does your question in fact have anything whatever to do with recursion?  The code you presented is not recursive.

Comment: @John Bollinger I have to use recursion but I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: @Nick, I can imagine how one would write a recursive solution to the overall task (but not *why*).  The fact remains, however, that the aspect you are actually asking about has nothing to do with that.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

There is no recursion needed. Just iterate over input chars and collect result in a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        sb.append((char)(c - 1)).append((char)(c + 1));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that explicit cast to `char` is required here, because `s.charAt(i) - 1` evaluates to `int` and without cast is processed by overloaded `append(int i)` method.

---

Okay, recursion. Here I split input into 2 halves and process each by using the same `encryptRecursively()` method, then join results. Each part, when passed to the method, is again split into 2 parts, etc, until size becomes 0 or 1 (thus we get a very simple implementation of [Divide and Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms)):

```
public static String encryptRecursively(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty())
        return "";
    else if (s.length() == 1) {
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        return new String(new char[] { (char)(c - 1), (char)(c + 1) });
    } else {
        int mid = s.length() / 2;
        return encryptRecursively(s.substring(0, mid)) // process first half of input
             + encryptRecursively(s.substring(mid));   // second half
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, but I need to do it recursively for practice with the concept.

Comment: Interesting approach to doing it recursively. I think the classic example, for a task like this, is to deal with `charAt(0)` and recurse over `s.substring(1)`.

Comment: @slim here are 3 answers around `s.substring(1)`, I tried to be a bit more original :)

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly tricky stuff for a beginner, but it's good stuff to encounter early and understand.

```
"" + 172
```

results in the string "172"

```
"" + 'V'
```

results in the string "V".

V and 172 are both represented internally as the same number, so what's the difference? The difference is that the compiler keeps track of the *type* of the value. 'V' has a type of `char`. 172 has a type of `int`.

When you perform an expression using a mixture of types, the compiler has to decide what the type of the result is. This will influence how that result is handled by routines such String concatenation.

As it happens when you subtract an int from a char, the type of the result is an int (the Java spec tells you this).

You can get around it by *casting* the type to something else.

- `(char) 172` is 'V'
- `(int) 'V'` is 172.

So:

```
  one += (char) (s.charAt(0)-1) + (char)(s.charAt(0)+1);
```

---

Recursion is a separate topic. Recursion works for handling sequences (a String is a sequence of characters) when you can do a chunk of work on a part of the sequence, leaving you with a new, shorter sequence, that you can do the same job on -- until finally you have the simplest case, which you simply return.

The simplest case, the one where the method returns without recursively calling itself, is called the *terminating* case. You need at least one terminating case, otherwise the recursive method will keep calling itself until Java runs out of memory for storing method states.

You have chosen your terminating case as being a one char string. I would instead pick a zero length string:

```
 public void encrypt(String s) {
     if("".equals(s)) {
         return "";
     } else {
         // do something with a string that's guaranteed >1 char
     }
```

Now you just have to work out how to replace that comment, by using up the guaranteed one char, and calling `encrypt()` to handle what's left.

```
 public void encrypt(String s) {
     if("".equals(s)) {
         return "";
     } else {
         return encodeOneChar(s.charAt(0)) +
              encrypt(x.substring(1));
     }
 }
```

That's it:

- when called with an empty string, encode() returns an empty string.
- when called with a non-empty string, encode processes the first char
     and calls itself to deal with a string that's one shorter.

Some languages, like Haskell, make recursion easier to understand, by representing the cases as pattern matching statements.

```
encrypted "" == ""
encrypted s == encryptChar(head(s)) + encrypted(tail(s))
```

(that's not real Haskell, but it illustrates the pattern.)

Recursion isn't quite as easy to read in Java, but the pattern is still there. `if(terminating case) { return answer for terminating case } else { calculate something, call self, return combined result }`

I'll leave you to implement `private String encodeOneChar(char c)`

---

Note that recursion isn't a good solution to your actual task in Java -- except in the sense that your goal is to understand recursion.

Comment: I tried to edit, but failed: Java `char` is 2 bytes, and `int` is 4. So none of them are 8 bits as you wrote.

Comment: yep, as now Java suggests to use `int` codepoints instead of `char`s to handle supplementary characters correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to use recursion, you can try something like that:

```
public static String encrypt(final String s) {
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        final char c = s.charAt(0);
        return new String(new char[] {(char) (c - 1), (char) (c + 1)});
    } else {
        return encrypt(s.substring(0, 1)) + encrypt(s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

the main idea here:

1. if input length is 1 symbol - we know what to do and just perform "encryption"
2. if input length is more than 1 symbol - we split string into "first symbol" and "rest of the string" and call itself on both parts

Comment: I see, this is exactly what I was looking for, but I'm not sure how this works. The recursion concept is still tricky to me. I'm trying to understand how this does what it does.

Comment: @Nick I've added some comments

Comment: I see! Thank you for adding the comments, very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a recursion but a simple `for-loop` through all chars in the word. You get the value of char with `s.charAt(...)`, but you have to convert it back to `char` for the desired resut. Append them to `StringBuilder` and return its `String` as the output of the method:

```
public static String encrypt(String s) {      
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        char a = (char)(s.charAt(i)-1);
        char b = (char)(s.charAt(i)+1);
        sb.append(a).append(b);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

Here is the recursion method as demanded:

```
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char a = (char)(s.charAt(0)-1);
        char b = (char)(s.charAt(0)+1);        
        return sb.append(a).append(b).toString();
    } else {
        return encrypt(s.substring(0, 1)) + encrypt(s.substring(1, s.length()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
one += (char)(((int)s.charAt(0))-1);
one += (char)(((int)s.charAt(0))+1);
```

Input:

> V

Output:

> UW

Comment: Don't just code dump a solution for people trying to learn. It does nothing to help them understand the problem they are facing

Comment: I'll downvote as I please, thanks. This answer is in poor quality compared to those already given

Comment: @redFIVE I guess it is a reason to downvote **"no-effort-expended post,"**. But if you read farther down in StackOverflow documentation you will read **"Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."** So basically you should leave a comment so the user has a chance to improve their answer before downvoting...instead of downvoting right away. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Yet instead of improving your answer you continue to complain about the downvote. Crazy, I know.

Comment: @redFIVE if the user wants an explanation he can ask me for one. I am going to leave the answer how it is for now...